# MSQL state "closing tables" taking double the time of a process

Tags: mysql, performance, mysql-5.5

I have a delete query that is taking a long time. When I check in `processlist` that status is showing as "*closing tables*". It is taking a long time to close tables.

*Example:*
I run a query and the total time is *1:42* seconds and in that *80-90* seconds are for closing table.

This is happening for all queries like `load data` , `select` and `insert`.

Below is *my.cnf* settings:

```
key_buffer_size = 2G
sort_buffer_size = 8M
read_buffer_size = 10M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 10M
join_buffer_size = 2M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 100M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 64M

#tmp_table_size = 100M
#max_heap_table_size = 64M
#max_allowed_packet = 64M

table_cache=1024
```

My meminfo

```
[root@localhost ~]# free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          7862       6686       1175          0         11       4091
-/+ buffers/cache:       2583       5278
Swap:        15998         18      15980
```

Please tell me what kind of changes I need to do in *my.cnf* file?

Answer (score 4):

**Closing tables** this thread is flushing the changed table data to disk and closing the used tables. This should be a fast operation. If not, you should verify that you do not have a full disk and that the disk is not in very heavy use.

This [bug report](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=41335) can be related as well.

**Further,**

MySQL closes an unused table and removes it from the table cache under the following circumstances:

- When the cache is full and a thread tries to open a table that is not in the cache.
- When the cache contains more than table_cache entries and a table in the cache is no longer being used by any threads.
- When a table flushing operation occurs. This happens when someone issues a FLUSH TABLES statement or executes a mysqladmin flush-tables or mysqladmin refresh command.

You can determine whether your table cache is too small by checking the mysqld status variable Opened_tables, which indicates the number of table-opening operations since the server started:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Opened_tables';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| Opened_tables | 2741  |
+---------------+-------+
```

If the value is very large or increases rapidly, even when you have not issued many FLUSH TABLES statements, you should increase the table cache size
For more information refer how MySQL opens and closes a tables here:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/table-cache.html

Comment: thank you for your reply. we have enough disk space(500gb+) and free ram (5GB+)

Comment: I too can see that you have enough space left but disk activity matters during execution time of query as well, How many rows are affected by `delete` query etc..

Comment: I have updated my answer, try by increasing `table_cache` size and see behaviour

Comment: I have a process/connection that is "Closing tables" for a long time. In my case, I was restoring from a backup and after writing 11GiB of data to a table, the disk was filled. The connection is taking forever rolling-back the transaction that inserted all those records. 2.5hrs later and it's still rolling back :/